How to display ACF group field and sub fields?
I have displayed a group field in block layout and sub fields before with get_field before but it isn't working.
<?php $about = get_field("about"); ?>
<?php if ($about): ?>
    <section>
        <h2>About</h2>
        <div>
            <?php $description = get_field("description") ?>
            <?php if ($description): ?>
                <?php echo get_field("description"); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $location = get_field("location"); ?>
            <?php if ($location): ?>
                <?php echo get_field("location"); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>

All that gets displayed is:
<section>
    <h2>About</h2>
    <div></div>
</section>

I was able to display them by doing this:
<?php $about = get_field("about"); ?>
<?php if ($about): ?>
    <section>
        <h2>About</h2>
        <div>
            <?php $description = $about["description"] ?>
            <?php if ($description): ?>
                <?php echo $about["description"]; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $location = $about["location"]; ?>
            <?php if ($location): ?>
                <?php echo $about["location"]; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>

But when the description and location fields are empty this is still displayed.
<section>
    <h2>About</h2>
    <div></div>
</section>

Should the about field display anything when it's sub fields are empty?

The data structure probably exists, even if the values might be just empty strings.

"Should the about field display anything when it's sub fields are empty?" - You need to define what you mean by “empty”. In this case, in addition to checking $about, you probably also want to check $about["description"] and $about["location"] before rendering anything

You could just extend your <?php if ($about): ?> to also include location of description with && ||
